# RestAction queue returned failure?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to make a Discord bot with Java and JDA (Java Discord API). I am getting this error after running this:

```
messageChannel.deleteMessageById(msgId).queueAfter(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
messageChannel.sendMessage("Survey says... DELETE IT!").queueAfter(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

They are going to an onMessageRecieved event. I am not having an issue with the bot or the event because in the event I also have other things working. So if anyone is able to help me with this, that would be great because for the last hour I have been googling. I thought it might because of its asynchronicity.